# Android video streaming of mp4 files with MOOV atom at the end

Tags: android, implementation, qt-faststart

I have implemented a streaming video player which could stream video formats including mp4 in Android using VideoView and asynctask. However some of the videos steams smoothly from the begining while someothers do not start to play until completely downloaded.

with my research I found the mp4 files with moov atom (like TOC) kept at the end of the file while creating is running that way.

I have seen a library which could solve this.

```
compile 'net.ypresto.qtfaststartjava:qtfaststart:0.1.0'
```

However I didnt get any reference on how to integerate this library to my project. Please post some references or snippets to implement this library to solve my issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, No! I have let those videos to completely download and stream.

Answer (score 1):

```
    File input = new File(path + "/input.mp4"); // Your input file
    File output = new File(path + "/output.mp4"); // Your output file
    try{
        if(!output.exists()) // if there is no output file we'll create one
            output.createNewFile();
        }
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("TAG", e.toString());
    }

    try{
        QtFastStart.fastStart(input, output);
    }catch (QtFastStart.MalformedFileException m){
        Log.e("QT", m.toString());
    }catch (QtFastStart.UnsupportedFileException q){
        Log.e("QT", q.toString());
    }catch (IOException i){
        Log.e("QT", i.toString());
    }
```

Here that's all